Быстрая сортировка. Если элементы в массиве повторяются, то слева элементы должны быть строго меньше за пивот? а справа больше равны пивоту?
В алгоритме быстрой сортировке с повторяющимися элементами часто бывает такое что в левой части остаются элементы меньше равны опорному элемента,а в правой части больше равны опорному элементу. Может ли такое быть? на всех сайтах пишется что элементы равные опорному должны быть справа от опорного элемента ?
вот код
void quickSort(Array& arr, int left, int right,int&comp,int&swaps)
{
    int i = left;
    int j = right;
    int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];
    
    while (i <= j)
    {
        comp++;
        while (arr[i] < pivot)
        {
            i++;
            comp++;
        }
        
        comp++;
        while (arr[j] > pivot)
        {
            j--;
            comp++;
        }
        
        if (i <= j)
        {
            swaps++;
            swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    
    
    if (left < j)
    {
        quickSort(arr, left, j,comp,swaps);
    }
    if (i < right)
    {
        quickSort(arr, i, right,comp,swaps);
    }
}


на всех сайтах пишется что элементы равные опорному должны быть справа от опорного элемента - не все сайты одинаково полезны.

На русской вики фраза про отношение элементов неточная (не соответствует разделению Хоара, перед которым она написана), на английской правильная, в книге Кормена тоже.

@MBo, вы имели в иду вот это -- "elements that are equal to the pivot can go either way"?

@avp Да. В русской написано, что слева ставятся меньшие, а описывается  алгоритм разделения, в котором меньшие или равные.

@MBo, ну, в английской, в общей части тоже написано, что слева от pivot меньшие, а при описании алгоритма они исправились... (уточнили очевидное)

@avp Ну в описании общего принципа сортировки это допустимо. А когда уже дело доходит до деталей разделения - стоит поточнее писать.
